# rabin2 error: Library handler has failed for 'core_pdd.so'

Tags: reverse-engineering, radare2

I tried to run `rabin2` (`radare2` util) and got that error:

```bash
rabin2
# ERROR: Library handler has failed for '~/.local/share/radare2/plugins/core_pdd.so'
```

I've tried to google the error and got nothing: "Library handler has failed for" query with quotes and about 3 results, including `radare2` source code.

This error is definitely thrown from [here](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/blob/4968d69f1848c2f9f2333d649a845009b59ba2a7/libr/util/lib.c#L365), but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

`radare2` was installed according to [author's instructions](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2#installation). [So was](https://github.com/wargio/r2dec-js#nix-users-linuxosxetc) `r2dec`. Also, I used `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.r2env/versions/radare2@git/bin"` to make it work.

At a quick glance, `pdd` and `r2dec` work pretty fine when executed from `r2` console.

Could you give me a clue how to fix that?

---

Versions:

```bash
r2 -v
# radare2 5.8.5 30144 @ linux-x86-64 git.5.8.4-98-g0cf6e7a5cc, 
# commit: 0cf6e7a5cc90554d735f4071b8b4888005e63428 build: 2023-04-08__22:52:24
uname -r
# 5.15.0-69-generic
lsb_release -a
# No LSB modules are available.
# Distributor ID: Ubuntu
# Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
# Release:        22.04
# Codename:       jammy
```

`r2dec` version: 5.7.8+ (commit [23819a6](https://github.com/wargio/r2dec-js/tree/23819a64c43d9f44fea94a14f308e343f3ab333f))

Comment: @applehelpwriter nope, I tried all above and nothing else :(

Comment: [Author's response:](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/discussions/22079)

R2-5.8.5 is pretty old, please update. My assumption is that you have inpaired versions of libraries. You can run make purge in the r2 repo to remove all system installations of r2, so you can start clean from there

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue earlier while trying to pipe the output to a file. Rabin2 is used in a terminal or a running instance of radare2. 
For example:

```
r2 /path/to/file
[0x00000000] > .!rabin2 -flags $FILE
```

I'd have put this in a comment, but I don't have the reputation.
Here is the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/rabin2.1.html) showing the flags and use case.